# Dragging collection of widgets around in Python using Tkinter

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

Alright, so to start I'm using Python 3.7 with tkinter.

I have a canvas and I can drag a label around with that using the mouse events. My next step is to be able to drag around something on which I can put more widgets. So imagine a box which has a text box and an image on it, perhaps a combobox too. That box can then be dragged around.

I figured perhaps what I needed was a frame widget on my canvas which I could then set up in the same way as I had done with the label. But this is where it seems to fall apart - clearly I'm doing something wrong.

Here's the code I've been playing around with, to no avail:

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("800x600")

def ClickedCallback(event):
    print(f'Clicked: coords: {event.x}, {event.y}')

def ReleaseCallback(event):
    print(f'Released: coords: {event.x}, {event.y}')

def MotionCallback(event):
    print(f'Motion: coords: {event.x}, {event.y}')
    canvas.coords(frame_id, event.x, event.y)

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=1000, height=600, bg='blue')
canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", MotionCallback)
canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(canvas, bg='green')
frame.pack()

l2 = tk.Label(frame, bg='red')
l2.bind("<Button-1>", ClickedCallback)
l2.pack()
l2['text'] = "Test"


frame_id = canvas.create_window((300,300), window=frame)
label_id = canvas.create_window((100, 100), window=l2)

root.mainloop()
```

My thinking here is that I attach the frame to the canvas and then the label to the frame so that, f I move the frame, the label within it will be moved too.

The above won't work though, and it tells me the following:

File "C:\Users\JohnSmith\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 2480, in _create
    *(args + self._options(cnf, kw))))
_tkinter.TclError: can't use .!canvas.!frame.!label in a window item of this canvas

I may be going about this in entirely the wrong way. I had looked around for something more, but if there's something I'm doing entirely wrong or an established way I should be doing this, I would appreciate it if you could point me in the right direction.

Comment: You have layout `l2` allready using `.pack()`. Why would you create it on the `canvas` again?

Comment: "Why are you making errors?" Well this is because I am not experienced with Python.

Comment: Did it work without `.create_window(..., window=l2)`?